# WooCommerce API and product image upload

Tags: woocommerce, google-books

I'm using the Google Books API to populate a WooCommerce database but I can't upload the images because I get this error:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id",
    "message": "#593 is an invalid image ID.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

WebP image link:
http://books.google.com/books/content?id=lYpxPQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api

I have found a solution that uses another API and converts the WebP image to a JPG image so that the API can upload it without problems, but for other reasons I don't want to use it.

Given the fact that with some plugin WooCommerce can easily handle WebP images, my question is:

Is there any way to not require uploading the image and instead just link to the WebP image?

Comment: Might be an issue due to File Types Allowed By Default, you need to check and allow the WEBP using a custom hook. might solve the issue with API upload also.

Comment: thanks I tried already and I tried now with two different plugins but it doesn't change. Same error. Probably the WooC APIs are not affected by those changes

Comment: Hmm, might the issue with the URL of the images, you can check the shared URL with the same problem discussed on the Woocommece GitHub page. I hope it will help you
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22557

Comment: thanks I already tried all those hints but no way the problem persists. I think it needs a deep hack on the woocommerce api code